# Field Level Help Lightning Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, helptext

I have used this code to display help text on fields. The help icon appears but it doesn't popup the help text on hover. Here is my code

Text Label
                  
                  
                    
                      
                        
                      
                      Help

```
            <div id="help" class="slds-popover slds-popover--tooltip slds-nubbin--bottom-left" role="tooltip" aria-live="polite" style="position:absolute;top:15px;left:103px;margin-left:-1.5rem;width:20rem;">
              <div class="slds-popover__body slds-text-longform">
                <p>Sample Help Text</p>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: You can try [Appiphony Lightning JS](http://aljs.appiphony.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Add [AL JS](http://aljs.appiphony.com/#!/gettingStarted)

And then bind the [popover](http://aljs.appiphony.com/#!/popovers):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('[data-aljs="popover"]').popover();
});
```

[DEMO](https://github.com/appiphony/appiphony-lightning-js/blob/master/public/demo-popover.html)